# Displaying the results on database using array

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using array to display the result I want to, It displays the date but not the location(site name). Here is my code in model

```
public function get($user_fname)
{
    $returnArray['sesdate'] = array();
    $returnArray['sname'] = array();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT sessions.session_date,sessions.site_name,CONCAT(user_fname,',',user_lname)as full_name FROM sessions 
    LEFT JOIN users using(user_fname) WHERE user_fname = ?", ['user_fname' => $user_fname]);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {                  
      $sesdate = strtotime($row->session_date);
      $sesdate = date("F j, Y",$sesdate);
      $sname = $row->site_name;
      array_push($returnArray['sesdate'],$sesdate);
      array_push($returnArray['sname'],$sname);
    }   
    return $returnArray;
}
```

And this is where I call the details.

```
   **where I call the date**
<td>
   <?php foreach($coachact['sesdate'] as $value):?>
     <label class="addplabelcoach"><?php echo $value; ?> </label><br>    
   <?php endforeach;?>
</td>  

**where I call the site name**
 <td>
 <?php foreach($coachact['sname'] as $value):?>
  <label class="addplabelcoach"><?php echo $value; ?> </label><br>
  <?php endforeach;?>
 </td>
```

Why is it that it displays the date fine but not the site name?

My controller

```
public function editview($user_fname){
    $returnData = array();

$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->checkIfLoggedIn();

$this->load->view('incf/header');
$this->load->view('schedulef/sced_tools');

$this->load->model('Schedule_model');
$coachact = $this->Schedule_model->get($user_fname);
 $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
$this->load->view('schedulef/Schedule_manage',[
                'coachact' => $coachact,'user_fname'=>$user_fname,'message' => $message

            ]);
```

}

Comment: Hello. The arrays are not the problem, you push to different keys. Just to be sure, is your database ok? Run your sql query in a client and check if it returns the expected result.
Also as a note, don't use `user_fname` as a foreign key.

Comment: The sql works perfectly, yes I know that's a wrong practice, but it should give me the output anyway.

Comment: yeah from your array_push should not be problem, if the site name was not call, i think the `$query` with $row->site_name is returning null @Kate

Comment: hows that possible, i can call the date on the row but not that site name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick simple to return array and object in codeigniter is using

`row_array()` to return 1 array

`result_array()` to return multidimensional array

**For your code that i have read. Do you trying to return only `sesdate` and `sname` ?**

so if yes

```
public function get($user_fname)
{
    $new_array = array();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *,CONCAT(user_fname,',',user_lname)as full_name FROM sessions 
    LEFT JOIN users using(user_fname) WHERE user_fname = ?", ['user_fname' => $user_fname]);

    foreach ($query->result() as $key => $row)
    {                  
      $sesdate = strtotime($row->session_date);
      $sesdate = date("F j, Y",$sesdate);
      $sname = $row->site_name;

      $returnArray['sesdate'][$key] = $sesdate;
      $returnArray['sname'][$key] = $sname;
    }   
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but only sesdate works and your code above has the same output.

Comment: Site name appears, but its from different row.

Comment: @Kate have you tried to check if the site_name in the $query ?
try check it echo "<pre>".print_r($returnArray)."</pre>"; before the foreach

Comment: Undefined variable: returnArray

Comment: site name has no value, empty, your right. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: than @Kate your site_name is null, check your sql statement properly

Comment: Been doing it everytime, it has session_date and site_name, the query has SELECT *, that means it select all including the date and the site.

Comment: Column 'site_name' in field list is ambiguous what is this?

Comment: is mean duplicated selected column, select it with table_name.site_name, change the table_name with your table

Comment: WHERE user_fname = ?", ['user_fname' => $user_fname]

in the last statement on sql @Kate i dont mind that is the true statement, or i am wrong, because i am not good in sql too, as i know where user_fname = ".$user_fname . is enough right ?

Comment: I believe it is wrong, because it will give u the column name, Unknown column 'Andrew' in 'where clause'

Comment: yes you where right,i got error because  both table "sessions" and "users" has site_name,

Comment: thank you, i rename the column name on the other table and its working perfectly :)